# Large RAM requirements for dense square matrix

Tags: c++, matrix, ram

Can anybody please help with the following problem:

The program I am working on needs to invert large dense square matrices. On my 8Gb RAM computer, the memory allocation fails for matrix sizes greater than approximately 16000, whether working in Linux/gcc or Windows/msvc.

This represents roughly 16000 x 16000 x sizeof(double) = 2 Gb.
Typically, future users will want to go up to even larger sizes, ideally without limit.

Storing in single precision is not enough: it only pushes back the limit by a factor sqrt(2), and anyway the loss of precision is not acceptable.

Is there a way around this problem?

Thanks in advance for your suggestions.

Comment: 2Gb if you only store the Matrix, but you are actually doing some costly operations, like inverting it. Also without seeing your code it will be impossible to figure out what's the problem.

Comment: If you are building a 32 bit program, 2GB is the limit you will have no matter what. Switch to 64 bit builds.

Comment: "ideally without limit" is not a specification any practical computer system can meet. You need to choose, based on your other performance requirements, whether your limit is the physical memory size or the available disk size.

Comment: @Sembei the code is `m_aijd.resize(size2); // is a std::vector<double>` where size2 = sizexsize;

Comment: @Pete Kirkham size=50,000 is the max reasonable I would consider

Comment: @n.m. Working on a 64 bit architecture already

Comment: Please show a [mcve], which would be a  short program that fails to allocate a matrix of more than 2 GB on your system, including the build command.

Comment: Are you actually just looking for a file based matrix library?

Comment: May I also add my humble opinion, that from the experience of 25 years in scientific computing in medical imaging, I have rarely come across matrix math, that really needed double precision. Dealing with single precision does not only save space, but usually almost double the performance of the program.

Comment: Can you say anything about the matrices? Do, they, for example, have any special structure? Do you in fact need to the invert them, or do you just need to solve equations?.

Comment: @caleth, no, already using lapack_dgetrf/dgetrs as well as a home made  gmres algorithm. Its the storage which is the problem. Wonder how the commercial FE codes manage several hundreds of thousands dof.

Comment: @dmuir it's an influence matrix for a Boundary Element Method. Nothing special about it. It's dense and not symmetric. Currently using LAPACK LU method and a home made gmres.

Comment: *"Wonder how the commercial FE codes manage several hundreds of thousands dof"* FE matrices are usually sparse.

Answer (score 0):

I followed up on your hints and it appears that I may have been barking up the wrong tree. The problem is with the Qt container class `QVector<double>` for which the allocation fails at matsize=17,000 i.e. 2Gb. Didn't find any documentation on this limit.

The following program using the `std::vector<double>` container and compiled with g++ allows to go up to matsize=30,000.

Requesting matsize=32,000 causes the KDE desktop to freeze, unfortunately with no exception thrown or caught, need to reboot.

I'll switch to std::vector which should be good enough for my purpose.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   int matsize = 16000;
   if (argc >= 2) {
        matsize = atoi(argv[1]); 
        printf("input size = %d \n", matsize);
    }

    std::vector<double> aij;
    int size2 = matsize * matsize;
    double mb = size2 * sizeof(double) /1024/1024;

    try
    {
        aij.resize(size2); // is a std::vector<double>
        memset(aij.data(), 0, size2 * sizeof(double));
    }
    catch(std::bad_alloc exception)
    {
        std::cout << exception.what() << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Request for"<< mb<<"Mb failed\n" << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        std::cout << "Unknown error, request for"<< mb<<"Mb failed\n" << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }

    std::cout << "Allocating "<< mb<<"Mb for the influence matrix" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Keep in mind that Linux by default allows for fairly wacky allocations to "succeed". Although a desktop freeze sounds like paging (i.e. ram is full so you read/write to disk which is dead slow and blocks pretty much everything else), keep in mind that when allocating huge amounts of memory, a lot of OS-related stuff comes into play.

Answer (score 0):

There is historical code that was deployed on the older DEC Vax and Sun architectures running Unix, called "vadvise()"  - we used it infrequently for image processing applications to get more explicit control over memory utilization.

I'm not sure if this approach will be worth the complexity, you can find a few more details here:

http://icps.u-strasbg.fr/~bastoul/local_copies/lee.html